# Convert code to POST

Tags: php, post

i have a script (php+html) full of forms and inputs, after the form is submited via post i can give the user a code (like was a GET form) q=test&t=3&u=9&q2=test&t2=3&u2=9&q3=test&t3=3&3u=9, then the user can put this code in a textarea for editing what he previously submitted

how to transform the code inputed in the textarea (q&t&u) to work like if it was submitted like a normal POST? like if i where using $_POST['q'], $_POST['u'] but from that code submitted (like foreach)?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is current form it is difficult to figure out what you want. And please use proper punctuation.

Comment: My guess is he wants to allow the user to bookmark the page shown after POST-ing a form - but that's a wild guess, the question is very unclear.

Comment: I thought I knew what you wanted. And then I thought I figured out what you really wanted. But after thinking about it, I still don't know.

Comment: jddddd, you need to choose sensible name and describe the whole picture, not only  particular question that just came to your mind.

Comment: "I want to split a querystring into an array"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$str = 'q=test&t=3&u=9&q2=test&t2=3&u2=9&q3=test&t3=3&3u=9';

parse_str($str, $data);

print_r($data);

/*
Array
(
    [q] => test
    [t] => 3
    [u] => 9
    [q2] => test
    [t2] => 3
    [u2] => 9
    [q3] => test
    [t3] => 3
    [3u] => 9
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is. that you want save form and later want to allow ur visitor to update these details. Best way to do is. 
you can generate a code(password) keep it in database along with record and provide it to your visitor

visitor will enter that code(unique) to get his record and can update that.